# Получить все ID из древа категорий

Tags: php, laravel

Есть древо категорий (коллекции). Для краткости вывода использовал `toArray()`

```
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["title"]=>
  string(3) "SSW"
  ["link"]=>
  string(3) "SSW"
  ["parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["user_id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2019-03-26 08:53:44"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2019-03-26 08:53:44"
  ["children"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["title"]=>
      string(24) "Пользователи"
      ["link"]=>
      string(12) "Polyzovateli"
      ["parent"]=>
      int(1)
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2019-03-26 12:07:08"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(19) "2019-03-27 07:56:57"
      ["children"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["title"]=>
      string(5) "Linux"
      ["link"]=>
      string(5) "Linux"
      ["parent"]=>
      int(1)
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2019-03-27 07:25:01"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(19) "2019-03-27 07:44:38"
      ["children"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(8) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(4)
          ["title"]=>
          string(24) "Пользователи"
          ["link"]=>
          string(12) "Polyzovateli"
          ["parent"]=>
          int(3)
          ["user_id"]=>
          int(1)
          ["created_at"]=>
          string(19) "2019-03-27 07:48:27"
          ["updated_at"]=>
          string(19) "2019-03-27 07:48:27"
          ["children"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Если ли способ используя функции Laravel, получить все ID категорий?

Comment: А что из этого категории? Вам нужно только id того что в `children`?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan это все категории. Мне нужны все ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = $categories->pluck('id')->merge($categories->children->pluck('id'))->toArray();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пошел разбираться.